# Modify wordpress theme php links

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a free theme (there is a demo available here): https://modernthemes.net/wordpress-themes/fit-coach/

It has special "classes" boxes, which on click lead to special "class" type pages. These pages are very hard for me to edit. What i would like to is to modity the php files, so these classes would lead to a given standard page. I tried to figure out where this is coded, however i have no experience with php, and with trial and error i was unable to find the right place.

Comment: looks like it is just a post type. - so a file called `single-classes.php` should suffice?

Comment: in a child theme of course

Comment: @Stender Thanks for the answer, however i dont fully understand. The "classes" have their own editor page as well, so i guess i need to modify more than that, as somehow i have to tell them where do they point right?